# Closest point to the origin

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Using Lagrange multipliers to find the closest points to the origin on the surface
$$x^2 -z^2 =1$$

My attempt:

The distance $f(x,y,z) = \sqrt{x^2 +y^2 +z^2}$

Then
$\frac{2x}{ \sqrt{x^2 +y^2 +z^2}}$=$kx$

$\frac{z}{ \sqrt{x^2 +y^2 +z^2}}$=$-kz$
$y=0$

Then
$\frac{1}{ \sqrt{x^2 +y^2 +z^2}} = \frac{-1}{ \sqrt{x^2 +y^2 +z^2}}$

But the last equation has no solution !
What the mistake that i have done ?

Comment: You have some mistakes in your differentiation and how you have equated them. Pls check my response for equations you get when you differentiate wrt. $x$ and $z$. $y$ is of course zero.

Answer (score 1):

Distance to origin $f(x,y,z) = \sqrt{x^2 +y^2 +z^2}$

Constraint $g(x,z) = x^2 - z^2 -1 = 0$

Applying Lagrange Multiplier method as asked in the question -

$\sqrt{x^2 +y^2 +z^2} = \lambda (x^2 - z^2 - 1)$

Differentiating wrt $x, y, z, \lambda$ we get

$\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2 +y^2 +z^2}} = 2\lambda x$

$\frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2 +y^2 +z^2}} = 0$

$\frac{z}{\sqrt{x^2 +y^2 +z^2}} = -2 \lambda z$

$x^2 - z^2 - 1 = 0$

Based on first equation, $x = 0$ is a possibility but it does not meet our constraint.

So we have $\lambda = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x^2 +y^2 +z^2}}$

Second equation gives us $y = 0$. Third equation for above value of $\lambda$ gives $z = 0$.

Substituting in our constraint, we have $x = \pm 1$.

So $x = \pm 1, y = 0, z = 0$ are two points closest to the origin and the distance is $1$.

As you can see from the equation of the constraint, it is a hyperbola with vertices at $(\pm 1, 0, 0)$ and of course vertices of the hyperbola will have the min distance from the origin.

Comment: @HussienMohamed when you put value of $\lambda$ in the third equation, it reduces to $z = -z$, which gives only possible value of $z = 0$ and when we check in our constraint, it does meet the constraint.